# What's wrong with my PHP unserialize?

Tags: php, serialization, fopen

I have a file with the contents:

```
a:12:{s:12:"a2.twimg.com";i:1308768611;s:12:"a1.twimg.com";i:1308768611;s:12:"a0.twimg.com";i:1308768612;s:12:"a3.twimg.com";i:1308768612;s:8:"this.com";i:1308768613;s:15:"f.prototype.com";i:1308768613;s:15:"c.prototype.com";i:1308768614;s:15:"a.prototype.com";i:1308768614;s:5:"w.com";i:1308768615;s:5:"s.com";i:1308768615;s:5:"f.com";i:1308768615;s:5:"h.com";i:1308768615;}
```

(It's an array of domains listed on twitter.com as keys and a timestamp as values)

If I call:

```
unserialize(fread($recentfile, filesize("./neptune_output/recent")))
```

(`"./neptune_output/recent"` is the location of the `$recentfile`)

It fails, but if I call unserialize with that string pasted in, it works.

I use the following code to open the file.

```
$recentfile = fopen("./neptune_output/recent", 'a+')
```

I've tried putting the `fopen` mode as `'c+'` and `'a+b'` but it won't work.

Do I need to post more code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just read it with `file_get_contents()` rather than messing about with opening it and working out the file size?

Comment: file_get_contents() you meant ;)

Comment: @John: heh. yeah. (I would fix it, but it looks like someone else already made the edit for me... now it needs to be approved...)

Answer (score 1):

a+ means: "Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it."

If you just want to read "r" is enough:

```
$recentfile = fopen("./neptune_output/recent", 'r')
```

See http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: And for simply slurping in the entire contents of a file, might as well just use `file_get_contents()`.